# Pagination with selectAll js not working properly

Tags: visualforce, pagination

i have a vf page where i do apply pagination using java script. All things are working properly except when i navigate to next page the SelectAll checkbox is not working properly. When i check selectAll checkbox it navigates me to the first page of list.

Vf-

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="Lead_SendGiftListExtension" recordSetVar="Lead" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

<!--- jQuery for search Table ----->
<!-- Jquery -->
<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>

<!-- DataTable -->
<apex:includeScript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

<!-- Search Highlight -->
<apex:includeScript value="//bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.9/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.css"/>

<!-- DataTable buttons -->
<apex:includeScript value="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.flash.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
<style>
    .filterMatches{
        background-color: #BFFF00;
      }
    .tertiaryPalette{
        color: #000 !important;
      }
    .dt-buttons{
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
 var accountsTable = $('[cid$="accountsTable"]').parent('table').eq(0).DataTable({
   //enables results highlight
   searchHighlight: true,
   //sets record lengths to show in picklist
   aLengthMenu: [
     [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
     [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
   ],
   "iDisplayLength": 10,
   //adds copy, print buttons...
   dom: 'lBfrtip', //l=length, B=buttons, f=filter(search), r=processing, t=the table, I=table summary, p=page controls
   buttons: [
     'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf',
     {
       extend: 'print',
       customize: function(win) {
         $(win.document.body)
         .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
         .prepend('<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />');

         $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
         .addClass( 'compact' )
         .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
       }
     }
   ],
 }); 
   $("#parentCheck").click(function() {
                $(".childCheck").prop('checked', this.checked);

            });
            $(".childCheck").click(function(){
                if ($('input.childCheck[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length){
                    $("#parentCheck").removeAttr('checked');    
                }else{
                    $("#parentCheck").prop('checked',true);
                }
            });
});
</script>

<apex:form >
<apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlock id="pg" rendered="{!selectedLeads.size>0}">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!saveGifts}" value="Send Gifts"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Budget &nbsp;
        <apex:inputText value="{!textData}"/>

        &nbsp;
        <apex:commandButton value="Set" action="{!toSetBudget}" reRender="set,get"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <apex:outputPanel >
          <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrapper}" var="a" html-cid="accountsTable">
             <apex:column id="set">
               <apex:facet name="header">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="parentCheck"/>
               </apex:facet>
               <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.checkBool}" styleClass="childCheck"/> 
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!a.lead.FirstName}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.lead.LastName}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.lead.Country__c}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.lead.Email}"/>
             <apex:column headerValue="Budget" id="get">
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!a.gift.Budget__c}"/>
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="References">
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!a.gift.Gift_Reference__c}"/>
             </apex:column> 
             <apex:column headerValue="Interest/Idea">
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!a.gift.Interest_Idea__c}"/>
             </apex:column>     
             <apex:column headerValue="Reason">
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!a.gift.Gift_Reason__c}"/>
             </apex:column>  
             <apex:column headerValue="Relationship">
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!a.gift.Relationship__c}"/>
             </apex:column> 
            <apex:column headerValue="Age">
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!a.gift.Age__c}"/>
             </apex:column>                          
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where is your select all checkbox? I don't see it.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="parentCheck"/> this line represents the selectAll checkbox. (function is given in JS)